# How to Get Started with Cardano Native Script

Tags: cardano-cli, script, javascript, native

What resources should you use to learn native script and in what order should you use them in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find fairly extensive documentation on Cardano Native Script (aka Simple Script) [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md).

In short, you can define a JSON object with a simple set of rules known as scripts to validate operations around:

- Payment (e.g. spending unspent transaction outputs, i.e. UTxOs at a payment address)
- Staking (e.g. withdrawing rewards at a stake/reward address and delegation)
- Minting (e.g. minting and burning of native assets under a policy)

Each script has a `type` defining different combinations of scripts required to validate an operation:

- [sig](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md#type-sig) a signature witness of a key
- [after](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md#type-after) a point in time
- [before](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md#type-before) a point in time
- [atLeast M](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md#type-atleast) of N nested scripts
- [any](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md#type-any) of N nested scripts
- [all](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md#type-all) of N nested scripts

Given these script types, you can have fairly complex nested validation rules and **order does not make a difference** within the nested scripts.

Comment: Master branch no longer contain docs on that address. I found it on other branch: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/1.26.1-with-cardano-cli/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md