# How to build a MultiSig wallet with a time delay element?

Tags: plutus, wallet, multisig

Any examples of tested libraries or code which enables multisig wallet where flow is more complex?

Example of requirements:

- wallet transaction needs at least 2 signatures
- wallet can be created with a "time delay" option, example "1 month"
- if 1 signature initiated the transaction, confirmation (aka "second signature") can be either an actual signature by another person/key or a "time delay of 1 month" passed since transaction was initiated

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use Cardano's Native Scripts (aka Simple Scripts).

This has been answered well here along with links to documentation: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/7959/1071

Comment: Arm chair response:

To add in, I don't think you can include the kind of time logic you're looking for via a Native Script but rather a Plutus script can better help with this.

It'll likely be a two step transaction process where the first is to initiate the transaction that marks the intent to spend a UTXO from the validator with say an NFT, and the second is to actually spend the UTXO using the NFT for access control and the script granting an isValid if either a certain second PK sig is included in Tx or a certain POSIX time has passed since since first transaction/NFT UTXO age

Comment: @EmmanuelBatse it can be done with a native script. Look at the link, specifically the "after" type which uses the "RequireTimeAfter" expression.

You're right that this is also possible with a Plutus script but it's unnecessarily complex and costly in this case.